# @Query с оператором OR

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

У меня есть такой метод:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.debitAccount.user.id=:userId OR t.refillAccount.user.id=:userId")
    List<Transaction> findByUserId(@Param("userId") int userId)
```

Но он возвращает не тот набор данных, который я ожидаю.

Мне нужно, чтобы он возвращал сразу то, что возвращают вот эти два запроса по отдельности:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.debitAccount.user.id=:userId")
    List<Transaction> findByUserId(@Param("userId") int userId)


@Query("SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE t.refillAccount.user.id=:userId")
    List<Transaction> findByUserId(@Param("userId") int userId)
```

Кто-нибудь знает в чем проблема?

[image: Transactions]

По userId = 100001 выдает:

Hibernate: select transactio0_.id as id1_1_, transactio0_.amount as amount2_1_, transactio0_.date as date3_1_, transactio0_.debit_account_id as debit_ac5_1_, transactio0_.description as descript4_1_, transactio0_.refill_account_id as refill_a6_1_ from transactions transactio0_ cross join accounts account1_ cross join accounts account2_ where transactio0_.debit_account_id=account1_.id and transactio0_.refill_account_id=account2_.id and (account1_.user_id=? or account2_.user_id=?)
Hibernate: select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.amount as amount2_0_0_, account0_.user_id as user_id3_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.address as address2_2_1_, user1_.age as age3_2_1_, user1_.name as name4_2_1_ from accounts account0_ left outer join users user1_ on account0_.user_id=user1_.id where account0_.id=?
Hibernate: select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.amount as amount2_0_0_, account0_.user_id as user_id3_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.address as address2_2_1_, user1_.age as age3_2_1_, user1_.name as name4_2_1_ from accounts account0_ left outer join users user1_ on account0_.user_id=user1_.id where account0_.id=?
Hibernate: select account0_.id as id1_0_0_, account0_.amount as amount2_0_0_, account0_.user_id as user_id3_0_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_, user1_.address as address2_2_1_, user1_.age as age3_2_1_, user1_.name as name4_2_1_ from accounts account0_ left outer join users user1_ on account0_.user_id=user1_.id where account0_.id=?

Transaction{Id=100009, debitAccountId=100003, refillAccountId=100008, amount=100, description=To User0, date=2017-09-01 12:00:00.0}
Transaction{Id=100011, debitAccountId=100008, refillAccountId=100003, amount=200, description=From User0, date=2017-09-01 20:00:00.0}
Transaction{Id=100012, debitAccountId=100003, refillAccountId=100006, amount=250, description=From User1, date=2017-09-02 12:00:00.0}
Transaction{Id=100015, debitAccountId=100003, refillAccountId=100008, amount=215, description=To account 100008 from account 100003, date=2017-09-15 13:20:48.089}

А жду Transaction-ы с id 100009, 100010, 100011, 100012, 100015, 100017, 100018, т.к. аккаунты 100003 и 100004 имеют userId = 100001

Comment: Судя по всему у вас есть `Transcaction`-ы, у которых одновременно и ` `debitAccount.user.id` и `refillAccount.user.id` равны данному `userId`. Вы хотите, чтобы такие записи в итоговом датасете дублировались?

Comment: Нет, дублирование не нужно. Нужно, чтобы были включены Transcaction-ы, у которых или debitAccount.user.id = userId, или refillAccount.user.id = userId, или debitAccount.user.id = userId и refillAccount.user.id = userId .

Comment: Но именно это и делает первый запрос?

Comment: Нет, почему-то не это. Я добавил то, что он выводит.

Comment: Рекомендую включить spring.jpa.show-sql=true - и посмотреть реальный sql запрос к базе...

Comment: Добавил. Но я в них особо не понимаю.